# Why doesn't JSONArray provide a contains() method?

Tags: java, arrays

Since `org.json.JSONArray` uses `ArrayList` internally, why didn't they provide a public `contains()` method?

Comment: I think the only possible answer is because they didn't.

Comment: Because they want the simplest interface? That's the concept of abstraction, you wrap something and provide a simpler interface

Comment: JonArray (the Oracle interface) extends List so, on this one, you could use the .contains method. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

Answer (score 1):

JSON is based on JavaScript and JavaScript doesn't have a `contains()` method on the `array` type. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

There is an `indexOf()` method [since version 5.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Specifications) but it became standard with JavaScript 6 that was released in 2014. So the JSON API is too old for this method, either.

[Also the standard document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) states:

> JSON was inspired by the object literals of JavaScript aka ECMAScript as defined in the ECMAScript
>   Language Specification, third Edition [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Specifications). It **does not attempt to impose** ECMAScript’s internal data
>   representations on other programming languages. Instead, it shares a small subset of ECMAScript’s textual
>   representations with all other programming languages.

(my highlight). So my assumption would be that the designers of the API aimed for a simple design.